# Install modx in a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, modx, subdirectory

I like my webspace tidy :)

Therefore if my root-folder is `html/` I would like to install modx (version 2.2) in the subdirectory `html/modx/`

For my website-visitors everything should be the same as if I would have installed modx in the root folder (`html/`).

I also don't want to do without friendly urls.

To make it even more difficult: I also really like the builtin modx file browser and I would love to use it for every file and folder in the document root (so every file inside `html/*` should be displayed).

(How) is this possible?

Additional question: if it is possible, is it better to reinstall modx in the subfolder or to move my installation to the new location (`html/modx`). As my installation is only a few days old, either option would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of MODx are you using?

Usually you would do an advanced installation (a separate version of MODx). You can move the existing MODx install to your sub-directory but you will need to update all of the *config.core.php* files and **MODX_CORE_PATH** constants to reflect this. You will also need to leave and update at least the *index.php* file in your web root directory. The config files that would need updating include:

- config.inc.php
- manager/config.inc.php
- connectors/config.inc.php
- core/config/config.inc.php

**core/config/config.inc.php** is the most important file and you will want to make sure ALL of the paths listed in there are correct.

The file browser will work fine providing you check all the URL and filesystem paths are correct in the Manager settings.

Comment: cool! so just as described here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Hardening+MODX+Revolution#HardeningMODXRevolution-ChangingDefaultPaths

Comment: Forgot about that! Same principal yes just in a publicly accessible sub directory instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess setting:

```
RewriteBase /subfoldername/
```

and install it as typically you do.